# Read multiple csv data files and sort the data into a new csv file

Tags: python, multithreading, csv

I am trying to read through multiple csv files in a folder, extract three columns (`key_resp.rt`, `key_resp_4.rt`, and `participant`) from each csv file and write these information in a new csv file. I am able to get the `for` loop running without write the result into the csv files. But with the code below, the new csv file (`sort.csv`) only contains the header of the data strings without the real data.

My code:

```
import os
import glob
import csv

#path contain the directory of the folder
path = r'C:\Users\Time estimates task\modified psychopy\reading data-2'
extension = 'csv'
os.chdir(path)
csvlist = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))
print(csvlist) #print out the list of csv file names
for file in csvlist:
    with open (file,'r') as csvfile:
        csv_reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile)
#        for line in csv_reader:
#            print (line['participant'])
        with open('sort.csv','w') as sortfile:
            fieldnames=['key_resp.rt','key_resp_4.rt', 'participant']
            csv_writer=csv.DictWriter(sortfile,fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter=',',extrasaction='ignore')
            csv_writer.writeheader()
            for line in csv_reader:
                csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Whenever you `open('sort.csv','w')` it rewrites the entire file. You need to append data to it (or leave it open while processing _all_ the files).

Comment: I am new to this. Do you mind give me an example of append data for the line open('sort.csv','w')

Comment: It's in the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) documentation, however there's a better way—see answer I've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would be possible to open the output file multiple times and add data to it (by using a *`mode`* argument of `'a'` for "append" instead of `"w"` for normal (over) writing—see the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function documentation—in this case it would be less awkward to just open the output file ***once*** and leave it that way while appending data to it from the input files, one-by-one.

This is what I mean: *(Note: no attempt was made to sort the data because you haven't specified how you wanted that done.)*

```
import csv
import glob
import os

path = r'.\_reading data-2'  # Path of directory containing data files.
extension = 'csv'
fieldnames = 'key_resp.rt', 'key_resp_4.rt', 'participant'
output_filename = 'sort.csv'  # Output filename.
output_filepath = os.path.join(path, output_filename)  # Output in same directory.

csvlist = [filename for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, f'*.{extension}'))
            if filename != output_filepath]  # Avoid reading any existing output file.
print(csvlist) # Print out the list of csv file names.

with open(output_filepath, 'w', newline='') as sortfile:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(sortfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',',
                                extrasaction='ignore')
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    for file in csvlist:
        with open(file, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
            csv_writer.writerows(csv.DictReader(csvfile))

print('Done')
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. Your code worked perfectly.

Comment: I also used 'a' argument for the with open() line, but the output file (sort.csv) contain two loops of data in different format. Do you mind give me a hint?

Comment: Can't say for sure, but as I said, using `'a'` append mode would be awkward. For one thing you would only want to write the header once, not for every input file read.